# putImageData will not draw to the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

After splitting up the tileset http://mystikrpg.com/images/all_tiles.png

It still will not draw onto the `<canvas>` I know it gets put into the `tileData[]` because it outputs ImageData in the `console.log(tileData[1])`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var tileWidth, tileHeight
ImageWidth = 736;
ImageHeight = 672;
tileWidth = 32;
tileHeight = 32;

    console.log("Client setup...");
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.tabIndex = 0;
    canvas.focus();
    console.log("Client focused.");

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "./images/all_tiles.png";
    imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, ImageWidth, ImageHeight);


    var allLoaded = 0;
    var tilesX = ImageWidth / tileWidth;
    var tilesY = ImageHeight / tileHeight;
    var totalTiles = tilesX * tilesY;        
    for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++)
    {
      for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++)
      {           
        // Store the image data of each tile in the array.
        tileData.push(context.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
        allLoaded++;
      }
    }


    if (allLoaded == totalTiles) {
    console.log("All done: " + allLoaded); // 483
    console.log(tileData[1]); // > ImageData
    startGame();
    }
    };

});
```

also

```
var startGame = function () {

   console.log("Trying to paint test tile onto convas...");

    try {
    context.putImageData(tileData[0], 0, 0);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw the image to the canvas initially, why are you:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, ImageWidth, ImageHeight);
```

Looks like you may have the parameters confused and are trying to fill the area with ImageWidth, ImageHeight... instead, draw it to 0,0

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

Here's your code adjusted a little bit:

```
var tileData = [];

var tileWidth, tileHeight
var ImageWidth = 736;
var ImageHeight = 672;
var tileWidth = 32;
var tileHeight = 32;
var tilesX;
var tilesY
var totalTiles;
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = ImageWidth;
canvas.height = ImageHeight;
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "all_tiles.png";
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
// draw the image to canvas so you can get the pixels context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

  tilesX = ImageWidth / tileWidth;
  tilesY = ImageHeight / tileHeight;
  totalTiles = tilesX * tilesY;
  for(var i=0; i<tilesY; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<tilesX; j++) {
      // Store the image data of each tile in the array.

      tileData.push(context.getImageData(j*tileWidth, i*tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
    }
  }

  // test it...
  // blank the canvas and draw tiles back in random positions 
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
  context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
    context.putImageData(tileData[ i ], Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height );
  }

};
```

There's no need to test 'all loaded' since it's just one image that you're splitting apart.

Comment: `context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);` just draws the big, uncropped image n the canvas. I honestly don't know why I had that there.

Comment: You want to draw the big image to the canvas, so you can step through the pixels and add all your tiles to your tile array. But you don't particularly want to leave that canvas where it is.

Comment: OK so.. so it draws on the canvas... then what?

Comment: I've modified the answer to suit, note I moved things around a little. Beware of dirty images and security issues when loading images from other domains.

Comment: Oh, I see now... but.. I get `Uncaught TypeError` on this line `context.putImageData(tileData[ i ], Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height );`

Comment: That is probably going to be the security issue I mentioned. Try putting your code on a server or trying a local virtual server if you have that option.

Comment: Wait... it works. Sort of. It will store the data all the way up to `tileData[86]` after that... a grey box is put in place for the stored tile graphic. That is really weird. Even though the loops run through the 483 tiles... help?

Comment: Actually, I'll just open up a new question for this.